# Inserir coluna Oracle, apos uma coluna existente

Tags: oracle

Estou precisando de ajuda. Tenho a tabela `USUARIO`, aonde tenho as colunas `LOGIN`, `SENHA`  porem preciso incluir a coluna chamada `DATACRIACAO`, porém gostaria de saber como inserir essa coluna `DATACRIACAO` após a coluna `LOGIN`, estou trabalhando com o **Oracle 11g**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para adicionar a coluna **datacriacao** na tabela **usuario**

```
ALTER TABLE usuario 
ADD (datacriacao date)
```

Porém não é indicado alterar a sequencia das colunas assim como você quer, [aqui](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/pt-BR/874e2ebd-92b7-4666-a9c9-a89b4b7628ad/add-coluna-na-tabela-aps-outra-coluna-especifica?forum=infrageral) é explicado o motivo

Comment: Esse comando por padrao inserir a coluna na ultima posição, porem precisa inserir ela apos a primeira coluna existente.

Comment: No caso eu ja tenho dados inseridos, não teria uma forma de fazer via comando, eu sei que no mysql se utilizar o comando AFTER + {COLUNA} ele inserir apos a coluna informada no after, no oracle não tem nada parecido ?

Comment: Alterei minha resposta com uma informação interessante que encontrei referente a alterar a sequencia de colunas após já ter dados inseridos na tabela

Comment: Faz um scriipt de insert (um programa como o sql developer faz automatico)  , dropa a tabela , recria a tabela com as posições corretas , roda o script de insert , mas na minha opinião muito trabalho por nada

Comment: Acredito que não há a necessidade assim como você comentou @Motta, pois o que vai determinar o retorno que ele vai ter é o `Select` que ele fizer. Pois se ao invés de `Select *` ele determinar a ordem das colunas `Select login, datacriacao, senha from usuario` o resultado sai na ordem que ele deseja. O que você acha?

Comment: Ajudou muito esse artigo, obrigado R.santos, me deu uma clareada no que preciso fazer.

Comment: Como disse dá para fazer mas não acho que fala o esforço.